# Add jQuery Event to Single Text Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I am customising this [nice website template](http://andreasviklund.com/files/demo/cv-template-tpy/) and in the `#profile` section I would like to add a textual link pointing to another section, `#contact`. I first tried the simple solution:

```
<a href="#contact">my text</a>
```

But it doesn't work.

I then tried to understand how to make this textual link trigger the same jQuery event as when you click on a section button; however, being a complete newbie, I have so far failed. In particular, my efforts have focused on inserting an `onclick` event into the `<a>` tag, as it is mentioned [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp), but without success.

Do you have some solution for this? :-) I am sure this is probably something trivial for someone who knows JavaScript; sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do 2 steps:

1) Add new `<li>` to `<ul id="menu">`

`<li><a class="newtab" href="#newtab" title="New Tab">New Tab</a><span>Get in touch</span></li>`

2) Add new div into `<div id="content">`

like `<div id="newtab" class="section">Content goes here</div>`

Other way

add function to your javascript section

```
    function showTab(tabname)
    {
        $("ul#menu li.active").removeClass("active");
        $('.'+tabname).parent().addClass("active");
        $(".section").slideUp();       
        $($('.'+tabname).attr("href")).slideDown('slow');
        return false;
    }
```

and add to link `<a href="#contact" onclick="showTab('contact');">my text</a>`

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! However, from my understanding, your procedure aims at adding a whole new section, while I would like to have just a textual link in one section pointing to another existing section, in the same way as what happens when you click on a section button.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand I think what you want is to add onclick event on  tag which will execute a function.

Then you should try the following:

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myJsFunc();">Run JavaScript Code</a>
```

And myJsFunc be like:

```
function myJsFunc() {
//Some code
return false;
}
```